# unable to fetch data in multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am unable to fetch the data in the second dropdown(which is depended upon the first dropdown). e.g. when we select country then the relevant state should be displayed but it doesn't. see my code.
my html

```
<?php
require 'dbconfig.php';
```

?>

```
<label class="control-label">Select Distict</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <select class="form-control" name=dist id=dist>
            <option value='' selected>Select</option>
            <?Php
            $ddObj = new USER($DB_con);
            $table= "tbl_dist";
            $sel = $ddObj->dropdowndist($table);
            foreach ($sel as $val) {
            echo "<option value=$val[dist_id]>$val[dist_name]</option>";
          }
            ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">Select Block</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
              <select class="form-control" name=block id=block>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

my jquery

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#dist').change(function(){


var dist_id=$('#dist').val();

$('#block').empty(); //remove all existing options

$.get('ddblock.php',{'dist_id':dist_id},function(return_data){
$.each(return_data.data, function(key,value){
        $("#block").append("<option value='" + value.block_id +"'>"+value.block_name+"</option>");
    });

}, "json");

});

});

</script>
```

ddblock.php

```
<?Php
$dist_id=$_GET['dist_id'];
if(!intval($dist_id)){
echo "Data Error";
exit;
 }
require 'class.user.php';
$ddObj = new USER($DB_con);
$table = "tbl_block";
$result = $ddObj->fetch_block($table,$dist_id);
$main = array('data'=>$result);
echo json_encode($main);
}
?>
```

class.user.php

```
public function fetch_block($table,$dist_id){
try
   {
     $sel = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE block_dist_id=:dist_id");
     $sel->bindValue(':dist_id', $dist_id);
     $sel->execute();
     $rs = $sel->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

     return $sel;
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
         echo $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Comment: Error messages in console?  Ajax request visible in browser devtools (hit F12, network tab) and returning correct values?

Comment: I think *but it doesn't* not enough  .. do you got any errors??  consoled your `return_data` and it returned the right values??

Comment: I didn't get any errors